# SparkR on Rstudio - cannot access s3

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have installed SparkR with R (and Rstudio) on EC2. I'm trying to read files located on s3:

```
temp  <- textFile(sc, "s3://dev.xxxx.com/txttest")
```

and get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be 
specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3 URL, or by setting the 
fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).`
```

I've tried to add my access key + secret like so:

```
temp  <- textFile(sc, "s3:{access_key:secret_key}@dev.xxxx.com/txttest")
```

and got:

```
Invalid hostname in URI s3://11111111111111111111:2222222222222222222222222222222222222222@dev.xxx.com
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Credentials.initialize(S3Credentials.java:41)`
```

I also tried to use

```
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=2222222222222222222222222222222222222222 
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=11111111111111111111`
```

before launching the cluster but to no avail.

Questions:
  1. How can I change the `fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId` and `fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey` properties?
  2. Is there a correct syntax I'm missing in the URI?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to set the keys within the SparkConf?

Comment: Yes.. but got : 
rdd = textFile('s3n://dev.xxx.com/txttest', conf = {'fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId': '111111','fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey': '2222222',})
Error: unexpected ',' in "rdd = textFile('s3n://dev.adk2.com/txttest', conf = {'fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId': '1111111111111,"

Comment: what's with the comma after your awsSecretAccessKey??

Comment: Yeah. I thought that too. it's different syntax imhm. tried without it with same response

Comment: I added the comment here not "Answer column" because I'm not sure that my answer is good for you.

I often use csv file not text file. In this case, I write as the following and it works well for me:

`read.df(sqlContext, path="s3n://xxxx:xxxx@bucket/mycsv.csv", 
   source="com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")`

And then, I recommend you to try to write like
`temp  <- textFile(sc, "s3n://xxxx:xxxx@dev.xxxx.com/txttest")`

Comment: `n`  in `s3n://....` seems like very important.