# SparkR unary operator error while accessing s3 bucket

Tags: r, apache-spark, amazon-s3, sparkr

I am trying to access my S3 bucket through R studio and SparkR by using this command

df < - read.json("s3a://sankar/user.json")

Error in -read.json("s3a://sankar/user.json") : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

May I know how to fix this issue.

@[SparkR on Rstudio - cannot access s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898880/sparkr-on-rstudio-cannot-access-s3) is also referring the same issue but no resolution.

Comment: The assignment operator is `<-`, with no spaces. `< -` is two separate tokens.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I figure it out the issue and forgot to update here.